# Looking for Android resource filter on ABI

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I am new to android gradle framework, so question might be obvious for someone.

My application build.gradle file have ABI split configuration to support platform specific builds ('armeabi-v7a’, 'arm64-v8a’, 'x86', 'x86_64’)

I have some platform specific resources like -
[snap for folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAAsq.png)

In case of ndk for shared library (.so) files following congifurations

ndk {

```
abiFilters = []
abiFilters.addAll(abi_filters.split(';').collect { it as String })
```

}  ensures to put platform specific shared libraries in respective APKs

Similarly, for resources do have some configurations filters?

I tried to create ABI specific folder in src/main/{platform}/res/raw but it didn't work.

Was checking on packagingOptions in android to exclude the unnecessary resources but there as well, we do not have ABI specific filters.

Stuck on this, if anyone has idea please help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by explicitly writing resource removal script, which removes the resource from apk directly :)

zip -d test.apk res/raw/<file_to_be_removed>

Note: test.apk should be unsigned here. If you use VSO pipeline, then put the remval script task after unsigned apk generation.